# PPTP VPN in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, gnome, vpn, pptp, centos

I recently installed CentOS 7 (GNOME), but I realized that there is no option for setting up a PPTP VPN client.

I tried to install `networkmanager-pptp-gnome`, but unfortunately it's not available in EPEL nor CentOS repository.

**How can I add PPTP VPN to CentOS?**

[image: No PPTP]

Comment: can you teach me to add `IPsec based VPN`. I am in trouble with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get from a: **yum search pptp ppp**  is it anything like:

```
[root@localhost src]# yum search pptp ppp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.openitc.uk
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * updates: centos.openitc.uk
===================================================================== N/S matched: pptp ======================================================================
pptp.x86_64 : Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
pptp-setup.x86_64 : PPTP Tunnel Configuration Script
pptpd.x86_64 : PoPToP Point to Point Tunneling Server

====================================================================== N/S matched: ppp ======================================================================
ppp-devel.i686 : Headers for ppp plugin development
ppp-devel.x86_64 : Headers for ppp plugin development
rp-pppoe.x86_64 : A PPP over Ethernet client (for xDSL support).
ppp.x86_64 : The Point-to-Point Protocol daemon
wvdial.x86_64 : A heuristic autodialer for PPP connections

  Name and summary matches mostly, use "search all" for everything.
[root@localhost src]#
```

If it is, then simply type: **yum install ppp pptp pptp-setup -y**

If not simply manually pull the required packages (there are no specific rhel7 builds on poptop at present, so the fc20 will probably suffice) e.g.

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://poptop.sourceforge.net/yum/stable/packages/ppp-2.4.5-33.0.fc20.x86_64.rpm
wget http://poptop.sourceforge.net/yum/stable/packages/pptp-release-4-7.fc20.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uhv ppp-2.4.5-33.0.fc20.x86_64.rpm pptp-release-4-7.fc20.noarch.rpm
```

Then, fill in the blanks and paste the lot into a shell prompt:

```
yourUsername=xxxxxxxx
yourPassword=yyyyyy
vpnServer="111.222.333.444"

modprobe ppp_mppe

mv /etc/ppp/peers/pptpserver /etc/ppp/peers/pptpserver.bak
cat > /etc/ppp/peers/pptpserver <<EOF
pty "pptp $vpnServer --nolaunchpppd"
name $yourUsername
password $yourPassword
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
EOF

chmod 600 /etc/ppp/peers/pptpserver
restorecon -Rv /etc/ppp/peers
```

Finally start a connection:

```
pppd call pptpserver
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the `NetworkManager-pptp` **EPEL** packages are version `1.1.0` & [do not work with the current version](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1467910) of `NetworkManager` in **Centos7**.

Rebuilding the **Fedora** package works without issue:

[Download the current `master`](https://src.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/NetworkManager-pptp.git/) & extract the archive

```
cd /path/to/NetworkManager-pptp-master
sudo yum install ppp-devel libnma-devel libsecret-devel
spectool -g -R *.spec
rpmbuild -ba *.spec
```

This creates:

```
Wrote: /home/stuart/rpmbuild/SRPMS/NetworkManager-pptp-1.2.6-2.el7.src.rpm
Wrote: /home/stuart/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/NetworkManager-pptp-1.2.6-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/stuart/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/NetworkManager-pptp-gnome-1.2.6-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/stuart/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/NetworkManager-pptp-debuginfo-1.2.6-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

- Install `NetworkManager-pptp` first then `NetworkManager-pptp-gnome`

[image: Adding a pptp VPN]

Kernel modules also need to be configured:

```
modprobe nf_nat_pptp            
modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
echo nf_nat_pptp > /etc/modules-load.d/pptp.conf
echo nf_conntrack_pptp >> /etc/modules-load.d/pptp.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I set VPN up on my CentOS:

1- I've installed PPTPD as follows:

```
yum install ppp
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://poptop.sourceforge.net/yum/stable/packages/pptpd-1.3.4-2.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uhv pptpd-1.3.4-2.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
```

2- I've edited IP setttings in /etc/pptpd.conf:

```
vi /etc/pptpd.conf
```

localip 192.168.0.1

remoteip 192.168.0.101-200

3- I've added user account in/etc/ppp/chap-secrets (assign username and password):

```
vi /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

usernameForuser1 *  setpassword1here  *

usernameForuser2 *  setpassword2here  *

4- I've enabled network forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

use the following command to apply the change:

```
sysctl -p
```

5- Configured firewall

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

6- Started PPTP VPN server

```
service pptpd restart
```

To start PPTP Daemon automatically when rebooting next time, use command:

```
chkconfig pptpd on
```

The log of the VPN server, by default, is combined with system log located at /var/log/messages

Comment: Are you sure you did the above on a bare Centos 7 box, as Centos 7 uses Firewalld, rather than iptables, as it's default firewall, and I suspect your Redhat 5 package (pptpd-1.3.4-2.rhel5.x86_64.rpm) may have a few dependency issues, such as the lack of a libbsd build.